The closed expression of Mellin-Barnes type integral
I have seen a beautiful identity about Gamma function in this article: article as follows:
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{-i\infty}^{i\infty} \left(\frac{B}{A}\right)^z\Gamma(\alpha-z)\Gamma(\beta+z)dz=\frac{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)B^{\alpha}A^{\beta}}{(A+B)^{\alpha+\beta}}$$
This can be proven by shifting the path of integration from a line to a rectangle where the left side is at negative infinity and the right side is on $\Re(z)=0$. Then, by summing the residues in the rectangular contour, we can derive this identity because the integral at negative infinity is zero.
However, a question has come up in my mind that what if we adjust the integral to the following one:
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{-i\infty}^{i\infty} \left(\frac{B}{A}\right)^z\Gamma(\alpha-z)\Gamma(\beta-z)dz$$
Regarding this integral, we cannot solve it in the same way as what we did in the previous one because the value of this integral at negative infinity is not zero. So, the problem is: is there still a closed expression for this integral? If yes, how can we solve it?
Any suggestions will really help! Thanks!
